# How can I set a RichText field on a Dexterity-based content type over the ZMI?

Tags: python, plone, data-migration, zope, dexterity

I tried to create an collective.nitf.content object using Script (Python) at ZMI.

The code I've used:

```
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName

news_folder = context.test_folder
wf = getToolByName(news_folder, "portal_workflow")
id="test_news"

news_folder.invokeFactory('collective.nitf.content', id)

n = news_folder[id]

n.setTitle('Test went OK')
n.setText('The test went OK.')
n.indexObject()
wf.doActionFor(n, "publish")
```

When I call `n.setTitle()`, the object is created OK, but when I call `n.setText()`, this error is thrown:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
  Module script, line 28, in mais_teste
   - <PythonScript at /plone/news_folder/test_script>
   - Line 28
AttributeError: setText
```

What am I doing wrong? I've researched for days and found no answer at all to this question.

Versions:

- Plone 4.3.3 (4308)
- CMF 2.2.7
- Zope 2.13.22
- Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr
  9 2015, 14:50:13) [GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)]
- PIL 2.3.0
  (Pillow)

Answer (score 4):

collective.nitf is a Dexterity-based content type, so there is no need to use setters here, you should assign the value directly to the field.

Also, note the `text` is a `RichText` field; you should use a `RichTextValue`:

```py
from plone.app.textfield.value import RichTextValue

n.text = RichTextValue(u'The body.', 'text/plain', 'text/html')
```

Take a look at the tests, specifically, the [test_catalog](https://github.com/collective/collective.nitf/blob/master/src/collective/nitf/tests/test_catalog.py#L81) module.

Comment: Thank you. It would solve the problem if i didn't get permission exception when try to import RichTextValue from plone.app.textfield.value at ZMI.

Comment: you can't access that module on the ZMI because of [RestrictedPython](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RestrictedPython).

Comment: Well, is there any other way to set an rich text that's allowed inside untrusted code by default? 

Without being able to set the text (wich is rich text), create an NITF item via Script (Python) are pretty much pointless.

Comment: the obvious question then is why you want to create such an object on a script via ZMI?

Comment: Because I have to migrate some content (10k+) to a server that I haven't access to filesystem nor I have the Quick Import product installed server-side. And I have not enough power to change any security or enterprise polictics. Then I have no option besides create such object on a script via ZMI.

Comment: See if your enterprise politics will allow the designation of RichTextValue as an allowed type via a mechanism like https://github.com/collective/collective.localfunctions

Comment: Being asked to migration 10k items only through the ZMI, yikes. Bad idea. No tests, no backups, asking for trouble.

Comment: Agree. Still: I found this way to do complex, not pythonic and unreadable

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need try use external methods for unrestricted acces in restricted python scripts.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).